# Finitely generated modules over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be finitely generated modules over a PID  such that $A\oplus B\cong C\oplus D$ and $A\oplus D\cong C\oplus B$. Prove that $A\cong C$ and $B\cong D$.

The only tool I have is the theorem about finitely generated modules, but I don't quite see the connection. Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

According to the theorem about finitely generated modules, any finitely generated module over a PID $R$ can be expressed as
$$
R^r \oplus R/(p_1^{k_1}) \oplus R/(p_2^{k_2}) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(p_n^{k_n})
$$
where $p_1^{k_1},\ldots,p_n^{k_n}$ are prime powers in $R$.  The $R^r$ is called the *free part*, and the other summands are *elementary divisors*.  According to the theorem, these summands are unique up to permutation.

Let $p^k$ be a prime power in $R$.  Let $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ denote the numbers of times that $R/(p^k)$ appears as an elementary divisor of $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, respectively.  Since $A\oplus B \cong C \oplus D$, the uniqueness part of the theorem tells us that $a+b=c+d$.  Similarly, since $A\oplus D = C\oplus B$, we know that $a+d=c+b$, and it follows from these two equations that $a=c$ and $b=d$.  This holds for all $p^k$, and a similar argument works for the rank of the free parts, which proves that $A\cong C$ and $B\cong D$

Comment: that was very elegant and clear, thanks