# When are two direct products of groups isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I was thinking about the following problem:

Suppose that $G_1 \cong G_2$ are isomorphic groups. Under what conditions on the groups $H_1,H_2$ will we have
$$G_1 \times H_1 \cong G_2 \times H_2 ?$$

Obviously, in the finite case we must have $|H_1|=|H_2|$. Also, it is easy to see that $H_1 \cong H_2$ is sufficient. Is it necessary as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you only interested in the finite case?

Comment: @FrankScience I'm interested in all cases.

Comment: In infinite case, $H_1\cong H_2$ isn't necessary. Note that $\mathbb Z^\omega\times\mathbb Z^\omega\cong\mathbb Z^\omega$. That's simply to say, $\omega+\omega=\omega$, where $\omega$ is the countable cardinal.

Comment: For finitely generated Abelian groups, it seems right, as a result of the structure theorem. In general, maybe Jordan-Hölder theorem works. I don't know.

Answer (score 10):

If $Y_1,Y_2,Z_1,Z_2$ are **finite** groups, and if $Y_1\times Z_1\cong Y_2\times Z_2$ and $Y_1\cong Y_2$, then $Z_1\cong Z_2$. The following argument (which I believe is due to László Lovász) uses no group theory, so it applies to much more general kinds of finite algebraic structures.

For finite groups $X,Y$ let $h(X,Y)$ denote the number of homomorphisms and $h'(X,Y)$ the number of injective homomorphisms from $X$ to $Y$. Since $Y_1\times Z_1\cong Y_2\times Z_2$, for any finite group $X$ we have
$$h(X,Y_1)\cdot h(X,Z_1)=h(X,Y_1\times Z_1)=h(X,Y_2\times Z_2)=h(X,Y_2)\cdot h(X,Z_2).$$
Since $Y_1\cong Y_2$ we also have $h(X,Y_1)=h(X,Y_2)$, whence $$h(X,Z_1)=h(X,Z_2)$$ for any finite group $X$.

Next, we show that $h'(X,Z_1)=h'(X,Z_2)$ for any finite group $X$. Let $X\setminus\{e\}=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Let $H_i(X,Z)$ denote the set of all homomorphisms $f:X\to Z$ such that $f(x_i)=e$. By the in-and-out principle, we have
$$h'(X,Z_1)=h(X,Z_1)-|\bigcup_{i\in I}H_i(X,Z_1)|=h(X,Z_1)+\sum_{\emptyset\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|}|\bigcap_{i\in I}H_i(X,Z_1)|$$$$=h(X,Z_2)+\sum_{\emptyset\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|}|\bigcap_{i\in I}H_i(X,Z_2)|=h'(X,Z_2),$$
the middle equality because $|\bigcap_{i\in I}H_i(X,Z)|$ is the number of homomorphisms from a certain quotient of $X$ to $Z$.

So $h'(X,Z_1)=h'(X,Z_2)$ for any finite group $X$. In particular, $h'(Z_1,Z_2)=h'(Z_1,Z_1)\gt0$ and $h'(Z_2,Z_1)=h'(Z_2,Z_2)\gt0$. Since $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are finite and have an injective homomorphism in each direction, it follows that $Z_1\cong Z_2$.

**P.S.** See [L. Lovász, Operations with structures, Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar. 18 (1967) 321-328](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/opstruct.pdf).

Comment: I thought the argument was due to Vipul Naik: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/427640/36434.

Comment: @Seirios: Vipul Naik seems to have rediscovered the argument Lovász came up with in the 1960s.

Answer (score 4):

The Krull-Schmidt theorem implies that if $G_1 \times H_1$ and $G_2 \times H_2$ have both chain conditions and can be written as finite direct products of indecomposable groups (these conditions hold true in particular when the groups are finite), then $G_1 \times H_1$ and $G_2 \times H_2$ are isomorphic if and only if the union of the multisets of isomorphism types of the indecomposable factors of $G_1$ and $H_1$ is equal to the union of the multisets of isomorphism types of the indecomposable factors of $G_2$ and $H_2$.  (This is equivalent to the statement that $H_1 \cong H_2$.)  An analogous statement holds for larger direct products as well.

I cannot comment on the other answer since I am new here and have low reputation, but I am not convinced that the multiset of irreducible characters is enough to recover the isomorphism class of a finite group.  If you disagree, please provide a reference.

Comment: That is true (at least, without some other assumptions on the group). On the other hand, you should be able to reconstruct the $H_i$ as kernels of the appropriate characters.

Answer (score 2):

It is a difficult question in general. You can look at some papers of Francis Oger, who worked on the question. In particular, there are links with model theory; for instance:

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ and $H$ be finitely generated finite-by-nilpotent groups. Then $G \times \mathbb{Z} \simeq H \times \mathbb{Z}$ iff $G$ and $H$ are elementary equivalent.

See [Cancellation and Elementary Equivalence of Finitely Generated Finite-By-Nilpotent Groups](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-44/1/173.extract) or [Cancellation of abelian groups of finite rank modulo elementary equivalence](http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/12315/10331) by Francis Oger.

Answer (score 0):

Riley, Hobson, Bence : "Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering",

Exercise 28.12, (a),(i)
Thus $C_6$ and $C_2 \times C_3$ have the same number of elements of any particular order, therefore they are isomorphic.

Exercise 28.12, (a),(ii)
Again, in summary, $C_2 \times D_3$ has $12$ elements: one of order $1$, seven of order $2$, and two each of order $3$ and $6$. (the same distribution of orders in $D_6$). Then the groups $D_6$ and $C_2 \times D_3$ are isomorphic.

Riley thus claims, that two finite groups are isomorphic, if they are of the same order and have the same 'distribution' of element orders.

Comment: This claim is not correct: the groups $C_4 \times C_4$ and $Q_8 \times C_2$ (where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group) are not isomorphic (one is abelian and the other is not), have both order 16 and have the same distribution of element orders (1 or order 1, 3 of order 2, and the rest of order 4).

Nevertheless, if $G$ and $H$ are both abelian, they are isomorphic if and only if they are of the same order and have the same 'distribution' of element orders (see, e.g., Steve Benson (1997) Students Ask the Darnedest Things: A Result in Elementary Group Theory, Mathematics Magazine, 70:3, 207-211.)