# Commensurability of two groups

Tags: group-theory, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

If two groups $G\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}$ and $H\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}$ are commensurable. Does it imply that the groups $G$ and $H$ are commensuarble?

Comment: $[H\oplus \mathbb{Z}\cap G\oplus \mathbb{Z}: H\oplus \mathbb{Z}]=[H\cap G\oplus \mathbb{Z}: H\oplus \mathbb{Z}]=[H\cap G: H]$

Comment: @Kamina, are you writing indices the other way round?

Comment: It's true when $G$ is finitely generated and nilpotent.

Comment: How? can you give some hints?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122839/when-are-two-direct-products-of-groups-isomorphic/1123044#1123044, use Seirios' answer.