# Step in proof of "Does $G\times K\cong H\times K$ imply $G\cong H$?"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism

I would like to know the idea behind the induction proof in the  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/427640). I added a comment to the answer, but the author has not been active for a year.

Comment: Use so-called “strong induction”: you assume the result is true for any group of cardinality strictly less than that of $L$, and prove it for $L$; you do *not* assume it holds if $L$ has cardinality $k$ and then try to prove it for $|L|=k+1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin good point, thank you. I'll try.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, then it is really easy

Comment: Which is why the OP just elided it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If either you or the OP wanted to submit an answer to this question, I’d happily +1