# Decomposing a finite group into a direct product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. It can be written as an [unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908033/uniqueness-of-the-direct-product-decomposition-of-finite-groups) direct sum of indecomposable groups $G_1 \times \cdots \times G_m$

Is there a method to find these groups  $G_1\cdots G_m$ if I can only :

- pick a random $G$ element $g$
- given $g$, get $-g$
- given $g_1,g_2, $ get $g_1 + g_2$

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is this an abelian group? If not, why are using additive notation? There cannot be a deterministic method, because your random element generator might keep returning the identity element! In these types of problems, it is standard to assume that you are given a generating set for the group.

Comment: what kind of operations  are prohibited?

Comment: It was not supposed to be an Abelian group, what is the correct notation ? If you are given generators, does this become really easier ?

Comment: Since the group is finite, there is a nonzero probability of picking the same (identity) element all the time. So I think that the problem is hopeless.

Comment: And if it gives a new $G$ element every time ?

Comment: If it gives a new element every time, repeat until you get the same element twice. You then have $G$ as a set, and the other two operations allow you to construct the group table.

Comment: If it gives a new element each time then it is not generating random group elements. It is very unclear what you really want to ask and why. What you are describing sounds very like a *black-box group* as defined by Babai, but you have to assume that you are given a generating set for $G$.