# Isomorphism of finitely generated modules over PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated

Let $A, B, C$ be finitely generated modules over PID $F$. It is needed to prove that:

a) $A \oplus B \cong A \oplus C$ implies $B \cong C$

b) If there is an embedding of A into B and vice versa, then $A \cong B$

I believe these should somehow follow from the structure Theorem on finitely generated modules over PIDs, however I am not proficient in algebra, so I have trouble putting the pieces together.

Comment: Hint: The decomposition of modules into free and torsion parts are unique up to isomorphism

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20664/finitely-generated-modules-over-pid?rq=1